# Can logical operators use tail-recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, sicp

```
(define (fast-prime? n times)
  (cond ((= times 0) true)
        ((fermat-test n) (fast-prime? n (- times 1)))
        (else false)))
```

This code is from *SICP*, chapter 1.2.6. The procedure uses *tail-recursion*, so it doesn't cause *linear recursion* when computed, in other words it's *iterative*. If I rewrite the procedure using **or / and** instead of **cond**, will it cause *linear recursion*?

```
(define (fast-prime? n times)
  (or (= times 0)
      (and (fermat-test n) (fast-prime? n (- times 1)))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right-hand side of `and` and `or` are tail expressions (see [R5RS section 3.5](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-6.html#%_sec_3.5)), so you can safely use those for iterative purposes.

Comment: `(and <expression>* <tail expression>)` and `(or <expression>* <tail expression>)` means *only the last expression* (in each of them) is in tail context (the "RHS" reference is unclear if more than two operands are present). :) That's probably because for `(if <expression> <tail expression> <tail expression>)`, the test is not in tail context. Similarly, there's no tail context for `not`, so we really should fuse `not` and `a` into one `not-a`, whenever possible.